# Tasks taking much longer then expected to complete

Tags: python

I've noticed that running distributed with two workers only utilises one core per worker.

The below script as an example takes around 20 seconds to get `times2` and 5 seconds to get `times`.

This means that each worker executed 4 tasks using a single core instead of in parallel using all 4 cores. I have also confirmed that only one core per worker is used using a resource monitor.

Why is distributed only using one core for worker and not executing the tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function is Pure Python it is probably bound by the GIL.  I recommend changing your workers so that they use multiple processes instead of multiple threads.  For example if the machines on which you are running the dask-worker process have four cores then you might start the dask-worker process as follows:

```
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --nprocs 4 --nthreads 1
```

Comment: To confirm, if executing on a 4 core, 8 thread cpu, would the start command be: `dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --nprocs 4 --nthreads 8`?

Comment: We generally start one thread per core.  `--nthreads` should probably be renamed to `--threads-per-process`

Comment: Does that mean that the --memory-limit setting is per core too?

Comment: Currently the value for --memory-limit is split between all processes